# usbip - Why is linux version different in linux-source package and uname -r?

Tags: kernel, dpkg

I am trying to install and run usbip using [this link](https://github.com/solarkennedy/wiki.xkyle.com/wiki/USB-over-IP-On-Ubuntu). But the version of linux tools does not corespond with uname.
I get an error when I try this:

```
/usr/lib/linux-tools/`uname -r`/usbipd
```

When running uname I get this:

```
root@allan-MS-7998:/# uname -r
4.2.0-42-generic
```

In /usr/lib/linux-tools/ is a folder named 3.13.0-100-generic and not 4.2.0-42-generic. I checked witch source is installed using dpkg.

```
root@allan-MS-7998:/# dpkg -s linux-source
Package: linux-source
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: devel
Installed-Size: 30
Maintainer: Ubuntu Kernel Team <kernel-team@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Source: linux-meta
Version: 3.13.0.100.108
Depends: linux-source-3.13.0
Description: Linux kernel source with Ubuntu patches
This package will always depend on the latest Linux kernel source code
available. The Ubuntu patches have been applied.
```

Comment: This kind of mismatch usually indicates that the `linux-source` package is out of date. Use apt to download and install a fresh version (`sudo apt install --reinstall linux-source`), and it should pull in the mountain of new dependencies that you need. Watch the output carefullly -you should see the new `linux-source` package download. If not, delete the older package from your local cache (/var/cache/local/archives/) and try again.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to change `corespond` to `correspond` and `witch` to `which`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install USBIP 2.0 on 4.2.0-42-generic I had to find the source code to USBIP. It is not /usr/lib/linux-tools/. The source was to be found in the folder: linux-lts-wily-4.2.0
I found the source in this folder: linux-lts-wily-4.2.0/tools/usb/usbip

Following the instructions in [this link](https://blog.danman.eu/usbip-utils-2-0-on-ubuntu/) I was able to compile, install and run USBIP.

Installing linux-tools-generic did not work. I had to compile from source.

I can now connect to my Arduino on my Raspberry Py's USB port from my Ubuntu computer. Much faster than using XRDP and running Arduino IDE directly on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Thank you for this description and link!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use backticks, not apostrophes. The correct command should be

```
/usr/lib/linux-tools/`uname -r`/usbipd
```

Comment: I did when used them in the console - but edited them in my question. Sorry - thought they looked silly.

Comment: Use this syntax instead: `/usr/lib/linux-tools/$(uname -r)/usbipd`

Comment: Thanks but the syntax is not the problem. Problem is that the folder i refers to (4.2.0-42-generic) does not exist. Instead there is a folder named 3.13.0-100-generic. And this folder does not contain the usbip tools as they first appears in a later version